# How do i fetch data inside a variable in promise in Ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I wish to fetch `data.ID` or `data.NAME` at array index 0 or 1 in my console log.

This is my `file.ts` code

```
ngOnInit() {
     this._listProduct.listProduct().subscribe(data => {
       this.list = data;
      console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

This is how my html and console window looks at the moment

[image]

I tried `console.log(data.id[0])` but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: Have you tried data[0].ID ?

Comment: worked :) but problem not solved , my php file is returning response "Result:1" , now if i try to match like this -`if(data[0].Result == 1){..///..}` doesnt work, what do i do ? in console it says undefined

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access ID of the first Object like this. This is an array. First, you should access the array element and then you can access the properties of the object like this.

```
const id = data[0].ID
```